Does neo4j has url which redirects to download latest cypher-shell debian package?
From https://neo4j.com/deployment-center/?cypher-shell#tools-tab I can get direct url https://dist.neo4j.org/cypher-shell/cypher-shell_5.19.0_all.deb ...but I would like to use cypher shell in github action and I want to download always the latest version. Therefore I don't have to update workflow file every time there is a new release. Hence the question as title.

There is no direct download link that automatically points to the latest releases.
If you only want the latest cypher-shell deb, you could use apt to download and install it from the apt repository.
Instructions on adding the apt repository are here:
https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/debian/#debian-installation
if you're using github actions, you could also use the neo4j docker image. It has cypher-shell installed already.

I have github action with neo4j as service. But I don't know how to call cypher-shell from that service. If I want to call cypher-shell in one of the steps.

In the end this is my solution:
jobs:
  neo4j-movies:
    timeout-minutes: 60
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      neo4j:
        image: neo4j:latest
        env:
          NEO4J_AUTH: neo4j/nothing123
        ports:
          - 7687:7687
          - 7474:7474
        options: >-
          --name "neo4j_service"
          --health-cmd "wget http://localhost:7474 || exit 1"
    steps:
      - name: Get movies dataset
        run: |
          docker exec neo4j_service wget -O /tmp/movies.cypher https://raw.githubusercontent.com/neo4j-graph-examples/movies/main/scripts/movies.cypher
          docker exec neo4j_service cypher-shell -a neo4j://neo4j:7687 -u "neo4j" -p "nothing123" "MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n"
          docker exec neo4j_service cypher-shell -a neo4j://neo4j:7687 -u "neo4j" -p "nothing123" -f /tmp/movies.cypher

I just run multiple docker exec to load movies dataset into database on initialization. So I reuse cypher-shell in service and I don't have to download it from somewhere.
